# How to install jnius in python?

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install jnius, I installed Visual Studio Build Tools, but when I enter `pip install jnius`, I get error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
'c:\users\вввв\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, 
tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\1D87~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
9ggkbbff\\jnius\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\1D87~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
9ggkbbff\\jnius\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\1D87~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record- 
hczhl1cy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full 
command output.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for jnius
```

How can I fix it?
I hope you help me

Comment: We need the full log to be able to help, not just that line (that tells you to read the log).

Answer (score 1):

`jnius`, which is [this pypi project](https://pypi.org/project/jnius/) does not support `python 3.7` officially.

A quick google search however yields that the module is now called `pyjnius`, see [this GitHub page](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius):

> Warning: the pypi name is now `pyjnius` instead of `jnius`.

So use the correct version and do:

```
pip install pyjnius
```

There are `whl` files for windows and python 3.7, so the installation should go smoothly. If not, you can check the installation instructions [in the docs](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#installation-for-windows)

Comment: where I can find this whl files?

Comment: They should be downloaded automatically by `pip` when you do `pip install pyjnius`

Comment: But you can always check the files section of the pypi prject pages. for [jnius](https://pypi.org/project/jnius/#files) only a `tar.gz` is available, but [pyjnius](https://pypi.org/project/pyjnius/#files) aslo has whl files which will be chosen preferably when doing `pip install`

Comment: Can you add the command you have tried and **the full error** that you get to your question?

Comment: The error is too big and I can't enter the entire error, so I will try to enter keywords: `jnius.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol  "_JNI_CreateJavaVM@12", 
 WARNING: Not able to assign machine() = AMD64 to a cpu value!` and I've already written the rest